# Text selected menu is not appearing on UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have UITextView present in UIAlertView. When I select the text from UITextView then those text selection menus i.e. copy,paste,select ,etc are hiding behind the UIAlert view as shown in following screenshot:

[image]

is there any way to make this menus in front?

Comment: Can you show the code how you added it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to describe the question well *(At least the code that you have used)*

Any way this below code worked me fine

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Select the Text" message:@"                    "  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];                 

UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 65.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
myTextField.text = @"This is the Data string";  
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];

[myTextField release];
myTextField = nil;  

[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
myAlertView = nil;
```

**Note**: Align the frame as per your requirement